# How to make item number's with adaptive in html/css ordered list with block children element of list item?

Tags: html, css

### Targets

1. Make ordered list as custom as `:before` pseudo element styling allowed (AFAIK arbitrary shape is impossible).
2. The spacing between container content edge (even with border when left padding is `0`) and item number (designated as `l`) also between number and item (designated as `m`) must be adjustable.
3. The item number with must be adaptive due to increasing digits count.

[image]

4. `li` could has children block elements as `div`, `p`, `figure`, etc.

[image]

### Problem

Below solution without positioning satisfies to first three requirements.

```html
ol {
  counter-reset: section;
}
ol li:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counters(section, ".") " ";
  margin-left: 4px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 4px 6px;
  background: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid skyblue;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
ol + li {
  margin-top: 6px;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aexcmk3h/)

[image]

But what about fourth requirement? Let's try to add child elements to `li`:

```css
<ol>
  <li>Alpha</li>
  <li>
    <ol>
      <li>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>Duis aute</p>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

[image]

Conceptually, `:before` pseudo element must take the one column (space below it must be empty until next `li`).
Currently, I know just one solution: positioning.

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: section;
}
ol li {
  position: relative;
}
ol li:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counters(section, ".") " ";
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px 6px;
  background: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid skyblue;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
ol li + li {
  margin-top: 12px;
}
ol li > li {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
ol li > li > ol > li {
  padding-left: 44px;
}
```

[Fillde](https://jsfiddle.net/aexcmk3h/1/)

In addition to ugliness, this solution reaches just first and fourth target:

- **Second target** We can not control neither `l` not `m` anymore: we can control just total spacing `l + m + o`.
- **Third target** No adaptivity: the `l + m + o` is actual only for initial digits count.

For the fouth target, vertical spacing adjusting is required, but it no too hard.

Could you suggest some alternative solutions? Does CSS flexibility ends here?

Comment: what about this: https://jsfiddle.net/hwczkxL1/?

Comment: @TemaniAfif, thank you for the fiddle! Please, check the item number 2: paragraphs those are block elements are in same row.

Comment: and this https://jsfiddle.net/aqu7e0pk/ ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif, looks like works! Thank you for the solution. Please tell me why we neet `100` in `grid-row:span 100;`.

Comment: made it an answer with detail ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an idea using CSS grid where I will tweak your initial code a little:

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: section;
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
ol li {
  display:grid; /* added this */
  grid-template-columns:auto 1fr; /* auto for the bullet and 1fr for the content*/
  align-items:baseline; /* keep all the text aligned */
}

ol li:before {
  content: "";
  /* make sure the bullet span many rows os it's kept on the first column
     and the content will placed on the second column
   */
  grid-row:span 1000; 
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counters(section, ".") " ";
  margin-left: 4px;
  margin-bottom:3px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 4px 6px;
  background: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid skyblue;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
ol + li {
  margin-top: 6px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Alpha</li>
  <li>
    <ol>
      <p>Something</p>
      <li>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>Duis aute</p>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Charlie</li>
  <li>Delta</li>
  <li>Echo</li>
  <li>Foxtrotg</li>
  <li>Golf</li>
  <li>Hotel</li>
  <li>India</li>
  <li>Juliet</li>
</ol>
```

Or like below:

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: section;
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
ol li {
  display:grid; /* added this */
  grid-template-columns:auto 1fr; /* auto for the bullet and 1fr for the content*/
  align-items:baseline; /* keep all the text aligned */
}
ol li > * {
  grid-column:2; /* all the content in the second column and keep only the bullet in the first*/
}
ol li:before {
  content: "";
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counters(section, ".") " ";
  margin-left: 4px;
  margin-bottom:3px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 4px 6px;
  background: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid skyblue;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
ol + li {
  margin-top: 6px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Alpha</li>
  <li>
    <ol>
      <p>Something</p>
      <li>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>Duis aute</p>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Charlie</li>
  <li>Delta</li>
  <li>Echo</li>
  <li>Foxtrotg</li>
  <li>Golf</li>
  <li>Hotel</li>
  <li>India</li>
  <li>Juliet</li>
</ol>
```